# Gcc 5.3.1 vs ANSI C re: Variable names and $

Tags: compiling, gcc

I have read [online](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables) and in print (the ANSI C book by Kochan) that one cannot use the dollar sign `$` in a variable name when programming in C. Yet, when I created the following code to test variable names as part of exercise 2 in chapter 4 of Kochan's book I am able to compile and run the code.

So, is GCC breaking the rules by allowing `$` or have the rules for variable names been changed to allow for the `$`?

Here is my terminal output:

```
user@computer# cat Answer-4_2_for_post.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int A$;
  A$ = 1;
  printf ("variable A$ = %i\n",A$);
  return 0;
}
user@computer# gcc ./Answer-4_2_for_post.c -o ./Answer-4_2_for_post
user@computer# ./Answer-4_2_for_post 
variable A$ = 1
user@computer#
```

Comment: This question would better fit on StackOverflow. Try to compile it using this command `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra ./Answer-4_2_for_post.c -o ./Answer-4_2_for_post` I also found [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs).

Comment: someone already asked [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/in-variable-name) on SO for c++, but maybe you will find some useful info there too

Answer (score 2):

Section [6.39 Dollar Signs in Identifier Names](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs) of the GCC manual states:

> In GNU C, you may normally use dollar signs in identifier names. This is because many traditional C implementations allow such identifiers. However, dollar signs in identifiers are not supported on a few target machines, typically because the target assembler does not allow them.